# Wordpress URL is http://ec2-35-176-85-228.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ after setting up CloudFront in AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I connected my custom domain using route 53 in AWS, that is all fine. However, after I created a CloudFront distribution and pointed my domain to it in 'Hosted Zones,' using type A, simple routing, my Wordpress URL has changed to http://ec2-35-176-85-228.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ instead of my custom Domain. Even the Wordpress /wp-admin page has this ec2 domain before the "/"

When I access my website using my custom domain, the homepage has my custom domain which is secured by SSL but every other page on the website has http://ec2-35-176-85-228.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ as the domain name, which is not secured by SSL.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this so that each page has the custom domain instead of this domain. I've spent hours trying to find an answer but I don't know how to resolve this...

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: You might receive a better response at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/